# Making a JFrame with a JMenuBar open in fullscreen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenubar

I have a JFrame that I want to add a menu bar to and then have that JFrame automatically open in fullscreen. If I just make a JFrame and set it to fullscreen with `f.setExtendedState(f.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );` that works fine:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class testframe {
    private static JFrame f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(testframe::createAndShowGUI);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        f = new JFrame("Test");

        f.setExtendedState( f.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);;
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

However, once I add a JMenuBar to that JFrame it will no longer open in fullscreen:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class testframe {
    private static JFrame f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(testframe::createAndShowGUI);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        f = new JFrame("Test");

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu j_menu = new JMenu("Test");
    JMenuItem j_menu_item = new JMenuItem("Test_item");
    j_menu.add(j_menu_item);
    menubar.add(j_menu);
    f.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    f.setExtendedState( f.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);;
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

What could be the cause for this?

**Update:**

Switching to **JDK11** solved the problem. I was on 15 before and also tried 14, both had the problem.

Comment: What operating system and Java version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> once I add a JMenuBar to that JFrame it will no longer open in fullscreen:

Appears in full screen for me. I use JDK11 in Windows 10.

However, the menu doesn't work because you have a coding problem. You need to add the JMenu to the JMenubar.

```
//menubar.add(j_menu_item);
menubar.add(j_menu);
```

Also, I've always just used:

```
 f.setExtendedState( JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
```

Comment: Lol the java and swing tags still get the quickest answers by the most knowledgeable peeps! +1. Nice to see you still around.

Comment: @ChristianJohann, surprising that fixed it, I've never noticed a problem with earlier versions, but glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `JFrame` methods in the correct order.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFrame {
    private static JFrame f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestFrame::createAndShowGUI);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu j_menu = new JMenu("Test");
        JMenuItem j_menu_item = new JMenuItem("Test_item");
        j_menu.add(j_menu_item);
        menubar.add(j_menu);
        f.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        f.pack();
        f.setExtendedState(f.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll update it in my question. However, even after fixing that mistake the frame won't appear in fullscreen for me.

Comment: Lol the java and swing tags still get the quickest answers by the most knowledgeable peeps! +1. Nice to see you still around.